# Create Rst Interpreted Text Roles to auto link sections

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Hello guys I want to create a custom role called STEP that links automatically the interpreted text to a section in another rst file if it exists, if it doesnt it keep it displayed as normal text.

Can I use it with autosectionlabel ?

Example:

```
:STEP:`interpreted text`
```

will automatically link to this step_def.rst file that has

```
interpreted text
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

if it doesnt exist, it just displays normal text

```
STEP interpreted text
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens when you try using `sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel ` to do that?

Comment: @StevePiercy I would have to manually add :ref:`step_def: interpreted text` everytime needed, I dont think its a good idea for a big project.
Also I dont want to use ref role, I want a custom role called STEP

Comment: I think you will get close to what you want, but with the word `STEP ` omitted. Please read the docs for actual syntax for [`sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html#module-sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel), then try it. Please report your results. In any case, you may be able to modify the extension to suit your needs by prepending `STEP ` and having it generate a link for the node if it exists, else not link it.